# Qt installer framework - check target directory and if it exists run uninstaller

Tags: qt-installer

I am looking for a solution to it if - existing installation to my program exists then :

1. Prompt page to - update, add or remove all components.
2. Remove the directory if installation file exits or run maintenancetool in that directory.
   I have tried answers to other questions on this site about solving the same problem, but none of the solutions work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

During fresh install of software, create a configuration file and store the installation details in that configuration file.

(In case of windows environment, you can store these details in registry instead of file)

And during installation find that file and check installation directory and other details.

Then you can show available options to user like,

- Upgrade Software
- Remove Software

On uninstall of software you should delete that configuration file.

For reference checkout this [demo project](https://github.com/anil-agrawal/qt-installer).